# Get Selected drop down attribute in frontend?

Tags: magento-1.9

I got all the drop down attribute value in this way

```
    <select class=" required-entry required-entry select" name="product[age]" id="age">
        <?php 
             $attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','age');
             $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
             $attributeOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
             foreach($attributeOptions as $each){?>
               <option value="<?php echo $each[value]?>"><?php echo $each["label"]?></option><?php
             }

}?>
    </select>
```

In Here attribute Id = age. Now i already store some value in database that should be in selected

[image: Like this i need to display in front end]

Please Help me for this
Thanks in advance

[image: Front end i need in this way]

Also i used in this code

```
<select class=" required-entry required-entry select" name="product[age]" id="age">

<?php $productId = $this->getProduct()->getId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($productId);
$selectedvalue  = $product->getAttributeText('age');

$atributeCode = 'age';
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product',$atributeCode);
        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

        foreach($options as $key => $value){


            if(in_array($selectedvalue,$value)){
                ?>
                <option>
                <?php echo $value['label'] ; ?>
                </option><?php 
                continue;
            }
?>
                <option>
                <?php echo $value['label']; ?>
                </option><?php 

        }?>
</option>
</select>
```

it also display all attribute value not highlighted selected value

Answer (score 14):

Use `getAttributeText` function to get Select box attribute value in frontend from 
Product object

```
 echo  $product->getAttributeText('age_group');
```

it will directly display value which is selected from admin for particular product.

hope this will work for you.

Comment: no it display only selected value i need all the value but selected value should be highlighted

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
<?php if ($_product->getData('attribute_name')): ?>
<?php echo nl2br($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

(or)

```
$productId = 1;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($productId);
$selectedvalue  = $product->getAttributeText('color');

$atributeCode = 'color';
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product',$atributeCode);
        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

        foreach($options as $key => $value){

            if(in_array($selectedvalue,$value)){
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($value); //get Product's selected attribute options Values
                echo "</pre>";  
                continue;
            }

                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($value); //get remaining attribute options Values
                echo "</pre>";

        }
```

you can change as per your requirement

Comment: check my edited question please

Comment: no it display only selected value i need all the value but selected value should be highlighted

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: No it display all the value only not highlight selected value

Comment: you have to change the things as per your need

Comment: yes i changed..

Comment: check my updated question

Answer (score 1):

​Go to magento website root directory​

> app\design\frontend\MyPackage\MyTheme\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

Edit and add the code which you want to display on front-end product page.

```
<?php if ($_product->getColor()):?>
    <?php
         $getOptionText = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getColor(), 'color');
         $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute("color");
         if ($attr->usesSource()) {
         $color_label = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($getOptionText);
         }
    ?>
    <div class="color">
         <div class="std"><?php echo $this->__('Color :- ') ?><?php echo $color_label; ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Empty drop down only displayed